# else if result are not giving output As they should be

Tags: c, error-handling

I have written this C code and when run it only shows output of

```
if (Marks<0 || Marks>100) {
 printf("Invalid mark \n ");
 }
```

whenever I enter any num digit as expected.

However, it should also perform one of the `else if` and show output accordingly when the first `if` condition is not true.

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int Marks;
  char Grade;
  
  printf("Enter your Marks \n");
  scanf("%f", &Marks);
  
  if (Marks<0 || Marks>100) {
 printf("Invalid mark \n ");
 }
  
  else if (Marks<=100 && Marks>90) {
    Grade = 'A+' ;
    printf("Great job! Your Grade is A+ \n");
  }
  
  else if (Marks>=90 && Marks<80) {
  Grade = 'B+' ; 
  printf("Very Nice! Your Grade is B+ \n");
  }
  
  else if (Marks>=80 && Marks<70) {
  Grade = 'C+' ;
  printf("Good! Your Grade is C+");
  }
  
 else if (Marks>=70 && Marks<60) {
 Grade = 'D+' ;
 printf("Not Bad! Your Grade is D+");
 }
 
 else if (Marks>=50 && Marks<40) {
 Grade = 'E+' ;
 printf("Need to study  More!! Your Grade is, E+");  
 }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `else if (Marks>=90 && Marks<80)` will never be true.

Comment: If you want to read an `int` from the standard input with `scanf`, you should use `%d` instead of `%f`.

Comment: Note that multi-character character constants such as `'A+'` are permitted but the value is implementation-defined and doesn't fit into a single `char`.  Your code doesn't provide any sort of printed assessment for anyone who is careless enough to score 40 or fewer points (assuming you fix the conditions from `else if (Marks >= x && Marks < x-10)` to `else if (Marks <= x && Marks > x-10)` throughout).

Comment: Consistency in programming is important.  Some of your `printf()` statements include a newline at the end of the format string but some do not.  The space before the newline isn't very elegant either, and the blank after the newline is not wanted either.  Your code will be easier for everyone to read if you format it more carefully, indenting the body of each compound statement.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use `scanf("%d", &Marks)` to read the input as a decimal instead of a floating point number. Also it looks like some of your IF checks are incorrect (Marks>=90 && Marks<80), it checks if Marks is higher than 90 AND lower than 80 which can never be true. I have quickly fixed them for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int Marks;
    char Grade;

    printf("Enter your Marks \n");
    scanf("%d", &Marks);

    if (Marks < 0 || Marks>100) {
        printf("Invalid mark \n ");
    }

    else if (Marks <= 100 && Marks > 90) {
        Grade = 'A+';
        printf("Great job! Your Grade is A+ \n");
    }

    else if (Marks > 80 && Marks <= 90) {
        Grade = 'B+';
        printf("Very Nice! Your Grade is B+ \n");
    }

    else if (Marks > 70 && Marks <= 80) {
        Grade = 'C+';
        printf("Good! Your Grade is C+");
    }

    else if (Marks > 60 && Marks <= 70) {
        Grade = 'D+';
        printf("Not Bad! Your Grade is D+");
    }

    else if (Marks > 50 && Marks <= 60) {
        Grade = 'E+';
        printf("Need to study  More!! Your Grade is, E+");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: technically you only need to check the lower limit on each branch, since the upper limit has been checked by the earlier conditions. I.e. after (x < 0 || x > 100), x is <= 100, so the next test can be just x >= 90, and then x >= 80 etc.